# Path variable [contenthash] not implemented in this context (webpack 5)

Tags: webpack

```
ERROR in [initial] [name].[contenthash].js
Path variable [contenthash] not implemented in this context: [name].[contenthash].js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
   output: {
      path: PATHS.public,
      publicPath: '/',
      chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].js'
    },
```

Started to migrate from `v4` to `v5` webpack , and solved most of the issues , but this issue I definately don't understand, here is the phrase from https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/ :

> When using [hash] placeholder in webpack configuration, consider changing it to [contenthash]. It is not the same, but proven to be more effective.

This is the only phrase about `contenthash` , and in 5 version of documentation , I see that `contenthash` still exist as option . Why webpack send me this issue ?

Comment: import WebpackChunkHash from 'webpack-chunk-hash' It was related to using of this plugin , when I've removed it , it started to work

Comment: Try to write `filename: "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js"`  in the filename field.